# distinguish single-block vs multi-block reads in Oracle explain plan

Tags: oracle, performance

If I am looking at a query plan in Oracle 11g, is there any way I can tell which operations will result in single-block reads and which will result in multi-block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TABLE ACCESS FULL and INDEX FAST FULL SCAN use multi-block I/O, other kind of access paths use single-block I/O.

Answer (score 0):

`FULL INDEX SCAN` reads the index a block at a time, from start to finish, It uses single-block.

`FAST FULL INDEX SCAN` reads the entire index, unsorted, as it exists on disk, And use multiblock I/O and read all the leaf, branch, and root blocks.

the same thing happen too in `TABLE ACCESS`.